# What's the best practice way to make a hover menu work for mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseevent, jquery-events, touch-event

I've looked around but I haven't found an answer to what seems to be a common problem.

I have a basic dropdown menu that is activated on hover (using hoverintent plugin for jQuery). It works fine for desktop browsers but for mobile devices that don't convert hover events to click as iPad does, it doesn't work. Here's the Javascript as it is now:

```
$('li.threecolumns, li.twocolumns, li.onecolumn').hoverIntent(      
function() {
    $(this).children('div').fadeToggle(fadeInSpeed);
},
function() {
    $(this).children('div').fadeToggle(fadeOutSpeed);
});
```

My question is: what is the cleanest and least problematic way to use clicks for mobile devices and hover for desktops for a dropdown menu? I had a couple ideas but not sure which:

1. Attach `onclick` event and disable hover every time there is a click.
2. Detect the ability to hover (not sure how this is done) and use a click handler if it's available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default iOs and some Androids implement a tap for hover event. It's handy, however, you need to make sure your top-level links lead to a valid anchor. The days of unclickable parent placers are gone and if that link leads only to a page with all the children listed as links, so be it. But make it go somewhere.

Comment: I was afraid of that... I just did a quick review of espn.com, sports.yahoo.com, skype.com, and a couple others and they're all doing as you say with a parent link that goes somewhere.. Is there no other way around this than creating additional pages for each top level nav item?

Comment: You don't need pages, hashes are sufficient. You can then show or hide menu items based on the location hash.

Comment: @TorstenWalter That's a great point. Hashes are sufficient. There's a few pros and cons but if you want to avoid additional pages then hashes are probably the best way to go about it.

Answer (score 3):

At least iOS automatically interferes with the `hover` event when there is an event handler so you have to tap once for the `hover` event and a second time for any `click` event.

Detection for hove is trivial. Check if the client supports `touch`. If there is `touch`, there is no `hover`.

```
if ("ontouchstart" in document) {
    // touch only code
} else {
    // "desktop" code
}
```

Comment: Thanks. My question then would be what about devices that are mobile but don't have touchscreens (blackberry for example)?

Comment: They should support events as screen readers do - `focus` and `blur` come to mind. I can't verify this though.

Comment: Thanks, Torsten, this was actually good information that I didn't realize I needed. Perfect.